# why is wlan0 interface visible from xterm but not from running program?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I'm running on an embedded linux buildroot OS and have installed a custom WiFi driver which starts in "wireless extensions mode".  I can see that driver from an xterm window (whether I'm running as root or a normal user) with the following commands:

```
cat /proc/net/dev
cat /proc/net/wireless
ifconfig -a
```

The wlan0 interface looks like this when printed via ifconfig -a:

```
wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 169.254.185.103  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 169.254.255.255
    inet6 fe80::24b:5bfc:8a9e:b148  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 00:23:a7:40:22:f1  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 40 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

But, when I run from my application, I can see all the interfaces on my system EXCEPT wlan0.  wlan0 is completely filtered out when viewed by my application.  I've tried these things from code within my application:

```
system("cat /proc/net/dev");
system("cat /proc/net/wireless");
system("ifconfig -a");
FILE* fopen("/proc/net/dev", "r"); fgets(...
```

I've run my application as both root and as a normal user and see the same results.  I've changed the ownership of my program to root:root and installed it as root with the s bit and that didn't help.  So, it doesn't seem to be a security issue...?

Any ideas?

Comment: that's just a typo when I wrote the question - I edited the question and fixed it

Comment: Provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Provide details of this *"embedded linux buildroot OS"*.  Are you using Busybox?  What shell(s)?  What C library?

Comment: What is the return value of the `system()` calls when trying to execute the `cat /proc/net/dev`?

Comment: what kernel version are you running. i.e. `uname -a`

Comment: maybe you should write a small example and paste it here, just like @sawdust suggested.